# How to access the request object in Page_Load function in Kentico 9?

Tags: kentico

I need to check for the presence of an anchor tag in the url, from within a transformation. I'm assuming that would be in the `Page_Load` function, but I can't seem to find any good documentation on this.

How can I go about it?
Thanks!

Comment: This seems like a good documentation https://docs.kentico.com/k9/developing-websites/loading-and-displaying-data-on-websites/writing-transformations/reference-transformation-methods

Comment: That page doesn't have anything about accessing the request...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anchors don't get passed to the server and therefore [`Uri.Fragment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.fragment(v=vs.110).aspx) is not present in the `Request` object. You can use the property only to construct URIs.

If you need to pass data to the server, use query parameters or hidden fields.

If you need to evaluate URIs stored in the DB, use Brenden's approach.

Comment: I wasn't aware that anchor tags didn't get passed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Within your transformation you can create a simple function using some similar code below:

```
<script runat="server">
    public bool UrlHasAnchor()
    {
        string myUrl = ValidationHelper.GetString(Eval("YourUrlColumn"), "");
        if(myUrl.Contains("#"))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
<script>
```

Now call it when you're setting your value like so:

```
<%# If(UrlHasAnchor(), "do something crazy", "don't do anything at all") %>
```

You can also [create a custom transformation method](https://docs.kentico.com/k9/custom-development/miscellaneous-custom-development-tasks/adding-custom-methods-to-transformations) too which would do the same thing.

Comment: How do I access the request object though? Thanks!

Comment: Use the `RequestContext` static class